# Complex Analysis Integration & Branch Cuts

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that the curve $C$ is any path between $z=0$ and $z=1$ which does not go through any singularities of the function below.  I'm trying to show the following:

$$\int_{C} \frac{1}{1+z^{2}}\,dz = \frac{\pi}{4} + k\pi\,\,\mathrm{for}\,\,k = 0,1,2,\ldots$$

Unfortunately, I can only find the $\pi/4$ portion via direct integration.  Where exactly is this $k\pi$ term coming from?  Since its an integer, I'm guessing that it's some kind of branch cut, but isn't this function single-valued?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\frac{1}{1 +z^2}$ is certainly single-valued, but it does not have a single-valued anti-derivative, because of the presence of poles. The situation is analogous to the function $1/z$, which is single valued on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\{0\}$, but whose anti-derivative (the logarithm) is multiple-valued on $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\{0\}$. In fact, we can consider a similar question for the function $1/z$:

> **Analogous question:** Suppose that $C$ is a loop in $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus\{0\}$ that begins and ends at the point $1$. What are the possible values of $\int_C \frac{dz}{z}$?

The answer to this question is given by the residue theorem, which says that $$\int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}_0(1/z)W_0(C),$$ where $W_0(C)$ denotes the winding number of $C$ around $0$. The number $W_0(C)$ can be any integer. On the other hand, $\mathrm{Res}_0(1/z) = 1$. Thus we can conclude $$\int_C \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi ik\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathrm{for}\,\,\mathrm{ some}\,\,k\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Now perhaps you can apply a similar argument to your problem?

Comment: Alright, I see that, if I wrap around one of the poles, then I get an added pi term (used partial fraction decomposition and integrated).  That makes sense, but my curve is from 0 to 1, and I need not wrap around a pole.  Why would I even include it?...

Comment: @user108149: I agree, the direct path from $0$ to $1$ makes the most sense. Why would you take another weird path? I don't know, perhaps because it makes a good homework exercise :-)

Comment: I suppose haha, but should I have to worry about adding these k*$\pi$ terms (not the exact term...but terms using teh same idea) for other line integrals with this possibility?

Comment: @user108149: I think the important thing to remember is that the value of the integral *can* depend on the path you are integrating over if the integrand has poles. Thus when integrating such a function, you always have to take into consideration what the path is doing. For simple paths, probably you won't have to worry about these extra terms so much, but you should always check to be sure....